# How to prevent system shortcut to apply to tmux?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm not sure if that can be done but, for example, if I press Ctrl+D while in tmux, it's going to close the current pane. If I press Ctrl+Z, it's going to put tmux as a background job. I would like these shortcuts to not apply to tmux (since 100% of the time, I've pressed them accidentally).

Is there any way to disable these system shortcuts for tmux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing softwares here.

`tmux` has nothing to do with `bash` or `zsh` or whatever shell you are using. You will have to look to that specific shell manpage, and disable those bindings. More info here: [How can I prevent tmux exiting with Ctrl-d?](https://superuser.com/questions/479600/how-can-i-prevent-tmux-exiting-with-ctrl-d)

I'll presume that you are using `bash` here. To disable <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> combination you can use `set -o ignoreeof`, that will make you need to hit TEN times this combination to actually logout. This is a good way to prevent accidental logout shortcut triggering.

To disable <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> (flow control keystrokes) `stty -ixoff` should be enough.

To make this changes persistent, add it to your `~/.bashrc` file. Crawl through this file to see if there is no `stty -ixon` and if you find it, also comment this line.